# Use gstreamer gtk signaling in QT application

Tags: qt, webrtc, gtk, gstreamer, glib

Hi i am writing a small Qt Application and part of that would be a webRTC video stream for which planned to use Gstreamer.
This is where i can into problems.

Naturally my app is a QtApplication and is thus managed by Qt a processes. Now while planning the code I learned that The component webrtcbin from Gstreamer relies on GLib and the GTK signaling.

so things like
`g_signal_emit_by_name`
or
`g_signal_connect`
will run into nirvana without the GLib main loop.

Now after researching and getting a headache over this i hope that i overlooked something and that the power of the crowd-brain can help me with a hint.

An answer to any of the following would help

Is it possible to have Glib signaling inside a QT app?
Is it feasible/possible to run both main loops (QT and GLib)?
Is there a good example on how to connect a gstremer pipeline with pure webrtc (not using webrtcbin)

Comment: You can start from https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/toolkit-integration.html?gi-language=c and adapt it to Qt.